# How can I do a conditional yield with Python?

Tags: python

I have to refactor some code. The original code was something like:

```
 while (yield _requires_payment(state)):
        did_pass_limit = yield _did_pass_limit(state)
        if not did_pass_limit:
            if existing_count is None:
                yield send_info_log("some stuff")
            yield send_info_log(f"more stuff")
```

So I refactored to:

```
    if yield _requires_payment(state):
        yield send_info_log(f"stuff")
```

If it matters, the function definition is:

```
@dialog(version="1.0")
async def _requires_payment(state):
    return await apply_payment_status_check(state, check_types=["window"])
```

But this creates an issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: Pylance says `Expected expressions`

Comment: copy/paste the entire error message in your question

Comment: It literally says: `E999 SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It's not what you told in the previous comment, you probably have info about where does the error comes from (line, char etc) and it's better to have all information in the main post instead of searching though the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `yield` as an expression there, [surround it with parentheses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions). Just like it was in your `while` condition.

(In [*assignment statements*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), like `x = yield y`, it's not needed, because that directly uses `yield_expression` instead of `yield_atom`.)

Answer (score 0):

`if` evaluates Boolean values
Try:

```
 if (yield _requires_payment(state)):
        yield send_info_log(f"stuff")
```

Comment: What is casting to a boolean expected to do that you wouldn't be able to use directly in an if statement?